# Why startActivityForResult not returning any result from AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult, startactivityforresult

I'm trying to set alarm using my app and for that I'm using Alarm Clock Common Intent as described [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#CreateAlarm).

Here's my code:

```
public void createAlarm(String message, int hour, int minutes) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM)
                .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, message)
                .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, hour)
                .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, minutes)
                .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI, true);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(intent, SET_ALARM_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
}
```

Here's `onActivityResult()`:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == SET_ALARM_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (data != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Alarm for " + data.getData().toString() + " has been set successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "data is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "resultCode not OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
}
```

The problem here is that I'm getting this `Toast` message: `resultCode not OK`.

So, why `startActivityForResult` is not returning any result?

Comment: Because most probably your activity will be killed before alarm clock. It is long time task (for example 15 hours). Returning result to starting activity is bad design for alarm I think. Thats why it isn't return any result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That `Intent` action is [not documented to return anything](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock.html#ACTION_SET_ALARM). Hence, implementations do not need to use `setResult()`, and so you are getting the default response.

Replace your `startActivityForResult()` with `startActivity()`, and remove your result-processing code from `onActivityResult()` tied to that `startActivityForResult()`.

BTW, replace all your `getBaseContext()` calls with `this`.

Comment: so how can I confirm that the alarm has been set successfully so that I can show some text to the user?

Comment: @HammadNasir: You can't. Whether the user chooses to set an alarm is between the user and the app that handles your `ACTION_SET_ALARM` action.

Comment: Then what can I do if I want to show some confirmation text to user?

Comment: @HammadNasir: Write your own alarm clock functionality into your app, rather than relying upon third-party apps. The user may not like this, and it will be a lot of work. It would be far simpler to eliminate your requirement for showing this confirmation text.

Comment: Okay! Got it. Thanks. Can you help with this one too: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45802830/6144372

Comment: One more question. Can we cancel alarms which were set using `AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM` intent?

Comment: @HammadNasir: There is `ACTION_DISMISS_ALARM`, but that is new to Android 7.0, and from the JavaDocs I have no idea how you can use it.

Comment: so that means there is no way of cancelling the alarms set using this intent in Android version before `7.0`?

Comment: @HammadNasir: AFAIK, there is no way to cancel the alarms set using that `Intent` before Android 7.0.