# How to get the deep link URI from AlarmClock providers ACTION_SET_ALARM intent for use with ACTION_DISMISS_ALARM?

Tags: android, alarm, android-alarms

I'm implementing a simple alarm system into my Android app using the built-in alarm clock app. I can create an alarm easily using ACTION_SET_ALARM and that works, but I need to be able to dismiss specific alarms should the user remove or change the equivalent event in my app.
The official documentation for ACTION_DISMISS_ALARM says:

The alarm to dismiss can be specified or searched for in one of the following ways:

1. The Intent's data URI, which represents a deeplink to the alarm.

But I can't figure out how to get the deep link URI for the alarm that was created. Could anyone please help me with how to do this? Thanks!

The post [Why startActivityForResult not returning any result from AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM intent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45907128/why-startactivityforresult-not-returning-any-result-from-alarmclock-action-set-a) implies that the intent doesn't have an official result, which is the only way I thought may work to get the URI.

I don't want to do a full implementation with AlarmManager and a custom alarm system at the moment unless I have no choice. If I can get AlarmClock to work that it would do exactly what I need.

Comment: I'm looking for the same kind of deep link for ACTION_DISMISS_TIMER. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @einUsername sorry, I didn’t find a solution so abandoned the idea